# Dart Streams unsubscribe

Tags: dart

Hello!

I'm trying to understand the workings of a streams in Dart.
Here is a simple example:

1. We have `Publisher`

   ```dart
   class Publisher {

       StreamController<String> _publishCtrl = new StreamController<String>();
       Stream<String> onPublish;

       Publisher() {
           onPublish = _publishCtrl.stream.asBroadcastStream();
       }

       void publish(String s) {
           _publishCtrl.add(s);
       }
   }
   ```
2. And `Reader`

   ```dart
   class Reader {
       String name;
       Reader(this.name);
       read(String s) {
           print("My name is $name. I read string '$s'");
       }
   }
   ```
3. And simple function `main()`:

   ```dart
   main() {
       Publisher publisher = new Publisher();

       Reader john = new Reader('John');
       Reader smith = new Reader('Smith');

       publisher.onPublish.listen(john.read);
       publisher.onPublish.listen(smith.read);

       for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
           publisher.publish("Test message $i");
       }
   }
   ```

As a result of the code I get 5 console messages from a reader `John` and 5 messages from reader `Smith`.

```dart
My name is John. I read string 'Test message 0'
My name is Smith. I read string 'Test message 0'
My name is John. I read string 'Test message 1'
My name is Smith. I read string 'Test message 1'
My name is John. I read string 'Test message 2'
My name is Smith. I read string 'Test message 2'
My name is John. I read string 'Test message 3'
My name is Smith. I read string 'Test message 3'
My name is John. I read string 'Test message 4'
My name is Smith. I read string 'Test message 4'
```

Everything works right. But if I try to change the cycle `for` so that after 2 steps reader `Smith` stoppes receiving the message, the message will only receive reader `John`.
Here is an example to change the function `main ()`:

```dart
    main() {
        Publisher publisher = new Publisher();

        Reader john = new Reader('John');
        Reader smith = new Reader('Smith');

        publisher.onPublish.listen(john.read);
        var smithSub = publisher.onPublish.listen(smith.read);

        for (var i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
            publisher.publish("Test message $i");

            if (i > 2) {
                smithSub.cancel();
            }
        }
    }
```

If you run this code, the console will only posts by **John**:

```dart
My name is John. I read string 'Test message 0'
My name is John. I read string 'Test message 1'
My name is John. I read string 'Test message 2'
My name is John. I read string 'Test message 3'
My name is John. I read string 'Test message 4'
```

But I think there should be 3 messages from the reader **Smith**.

Please tell me if all I know right? If not, help me, please, to understand why this happens.

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Either create a sync `StreamController`

```dart
StreamController<String> _publishCtrl = new StreamController<String>(sync: true);
```

or allow the controller to process the items before sending new one

```dart
  int i = 0;
  Future.doWhile(() {
    i++;

    publisher.publish("Test message $i");

    if (i > 2) {
      subscriptions
        ..forEach((s) => s.cancel())
        ..clear();
    }
    return i < 5;
  }
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer. I added to the end of the question code that you suggest, but the result did not change. As a result of the program I get information about what messages are received only reader **John**. But it seems to me that the first 3 posts should receive and **Smith**

Comment: I missed that you already stored the `StreamSubscription`. My answer is invalid then. This is only another way to store and cancel a set of  `StreamSubscriptions`.

Comment: I guess the problem is that your Stream is async and the published items are only transmitted to listeners after your for loop has finished. So the subscription was already canceled before the first item arrived for `John`. I updated my answer.

Comment: Thank you so much! You are awesome! Much of what I could not understand in the Dart, I learned it from your answers!